# Which Narnia book corresponds to which planet?

Tags: planets, the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis

In case people haven't heard of it, there's a *brilliant* theory which suggests that each of C S Lewis's seven Narnia books corresponds to one of the seven 'planets' of pre-Copernican astronomy (the Sun, the Moon, Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn). For more details see [here](http://www.planetnarnia.com/).

I've been trying to work out (without going out to spend a tenner on Michael Ward's book!) which 'planet' corresponds to which Narnia book. Some nosing around the Planet Narnia website turned up only one correspondence:

- Jupiter <--> *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*

I also remember that the 'Old Father Time' who appears asleep in *The Silver Chair* was Saturn in an earlier version of the book, and that this was used as evidence for:

- Saturn <--> *The Silver Chair*

Since the main aim of the eponymous characters in *The Horse and his Boy* is to deliver a message, I would also guess:

- Mercury <--> *The Horse and his Boy*

**What are the other four correspondences?** A simple answer backed up by a link would be great, but some explanation for how all seven correspondences match up (things like (Horse & his Boy) -> message -> Mercury) would be even more appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want to spend a tenner, is there no way you can visit a bookstore (or library) and leaf through the book?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hopefully someone can give a more detailed answer which matches up the characteristics of the planets to story elements, but just looking on the Planet Narnia website I see there are sub-pages for each planet which say which book the author believes was meant to be associated with it, and which list some of the qualities of that planet:

[Jupiter](http://www.planetnarnia.com/planet-narnia/the-seven-heavens/jupiter) - The Lion, The Witch and the Wardrobe. Qualities: "kingliness; magnanimity; festal joy; tragic splendour; summer-time tranquillity"

[Mars](http://www.planetnarnia.com/planet-narnia/the-seven-heavens/mars) - Prince Caspian. Qualities: "vegetative growth in the month of March; military strength and knightly discipline; courage and orderliness or cruelty and lawlessness"

[Sol](http://www.planetnarnia.com/planet-narnia/the-seven-heavens/sol) - The Voyage of the 'Dawn Treader'. Qualities: "wisdom; liberality; generosity; freedom; riches; enlightenment; opposition to greed"

[Luna](http://www.planetnarnia.com/planet-narnia/the-seven-heavens/luna) - The Silver Chair. Qualities: "envy; wateriness; confusion; lunacy; boundary between certainty and mutability; sponsor of hunting and wandering"

[Mercury](http://www.planetnarnia.com/planet-narnia/the-seven-heavens/mercury) - The Horse and His Boy. Qualities: "swiftness; heraldry; skill in speech and learning; bright alacrity; ability to divide and recombine"

[Venus](http://www.planetnarnia.com/planet-narnia/the-seven-heavens/venus) - The Magician's Nephew. Qualities: "sweetness; warmth; beauty; laughter; motherliness; sexuality; fertility; vitality; creativity"

[Saturn](http://www.planetnarnia.com/planet-narnia/the-seven-heavens/saturn) - The Last Battle. Qualities: "pestilence, treachery, disaster, and death, or godly sorrow, penitence and contemplation"